# Torque perpendicular to angular momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, torque

if torque acts on body then magnitude of angular momentum remains same WHY?? 
Another think which I have to ask that is this statement valid for both rigid and non rigid body or only for rigid body??

Comment: $\dot L = \tau$ So what are you actually asking?

Answer (score 1):

No, if a torque acts on a body the angular momentum does NOT remain constant at all, both in magnitude and direction. It may remain constant in the direction where net torque is zero.

For example, for the basic example of a person applying a force on a door perpendicular to its plane, the components of the angular momentum along both the X- and Y- axes about the hinge (Z- axes being taken along the door' plane) remain zero.

\begin{equation*}
\frac{dL}{dt} =\tau 
\end{equation*}

The second part of your question is unclear. By a non-rigid body are you referring to a particle? Ïf so, torques are not taken for particles. Particles are assumed to have a translational motion only.